# Raspbian Jessie, Application Autostart

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, startup, raspbian, iceweasel

I have raspbian jessie installed on raspberry pi. I have tried to configure iceweasel web browser to start on boot up.

Under /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart this has been configure

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@iceweasel
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

Nothing has worked, i have tried other browsers and applications, nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Raspberry version, I do not have Iceweasel installed and I use Epiphany as web browser.

In a terminal execute Epiphany and if a web browser runs, then try to change in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` file, Iceweasel by Epiphany.

If this does not work then put in a cron (crontab -e), put this line to run when the Raspberry boots:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/epiphany
```